# File contents to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an output of a multidimensional array in this form:

```
Array
(
[MiddleName] => de
[FirstName] => Lianne
[Id] => 2937
[LastName] => Natris
)
Array
(
[MiddleName] => de
[FirstName] => Herman
[Id] => 2215
[LastName] => Groot
)
```

I have f**cked up the user data by playing with API, so I need to fix it now. This output is the only correct data I have left. The API update function works as follows:

```
$grp = array('LastName' => 'John', 'MiddleName' => 'van'); 
$rID = $app->dsUpdate("Contact", $cID, $grp);
```

How can I parse this output back to multi-array? I have very limited knowledge of regex :((

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you output it like that? Or do you get it from an external source? I have a feeling you might be doing something very inefficient.

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: @kba Unfortunately that's the only source I have

Comment: @michi I need to use this data to update user data in online CRM by using their API

Comment: How come it's in this format in the first place? How come you can't get to the original source? Is any of this under your control?

Comment: @kiri ok, I mean, how exactly should the result look like, could you create an example?

Comment: I have f**cked up the user data by playing with API, so I need to fix it now. This output is the only correct data I have left.
The API update function works as follows:
$grp = array('LastName'  => 'John', 'MiddleName'  => 'van');
$rID = $app->dsUpdate("Contact", $cID, $grp);

Comment: @kiri hope my regex hack will work for you then :)

Comment: Btw, please update the question to add that background information as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `print_r()` is not really suitable to "reverse engineer" the original structure.

If you wish to just work with string representations, you could use [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/serialize) and [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/unserialize) for that instead.

```
// turn array into a string format
$str = serialize($arr);

// get it back into an array
var_dump(unserialize($str));
```

You could also look at `var_export()`, if you want to write the structure into a script file (like a simple cache) or `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` if the structure needs to be shared with JavaScript for instance.

**Update**

If you really have no choice:

```
$arrays = array();
if (preg_match_all('/^Array\s*\((.*?)\)/ms', $s, $matches)) {
  foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    if (preg_match_all('/\[([^]]+)\] => (.*)/', $match, $params)) {
      $arrays[] = array_combine($params[1], $params[2]);
    }
  }
  print_r($arrays);
} else {
  die("Arrrrgh");
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KKAvBb)

Comment: Jack, your regex hack works like a charm! Thank you for saving my ass! :)